# ASTER DEMs multidirectional hillshades

Tags: qgis, hillshade, aster

I am trying to produce a multidirectional hillshade from ASTER DEMs in QGIS. basically I am trying to achieve something similar to this

[image]

which is a screenshot from this layer https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/World_Hillshade/MapServer 
but there the problem is that I can not print maps in the high resolution I need.
so i thought i do it myself but when I 
apply these settings

[image]

that work for other DEMs very nicely I get a terrible image for Aster.

[image]

I kind of suspect it has to do with the fact that I can not apply the scale correction factor of 111120 (in the Scale ratio vert. units to horiz. box) which I usually do for aster.
any thoughts for how I can make this work?

Comment: You should check the vertical scale. If the original file is in Geographic projection, 1x is too high (as it is in degrees not meters) and illumination is distorted. Try a value of 0,00001 at Z factor options.